# CodeMirror - Using RegEx with overlay

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

I can't seem to find an example of anyone using RegEx matches to create an overlay in CodeMirror.  The [Moustaches](http://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html) example matching one thing at a time seems simple enough, but in the API, it says that the RegEx match returns the array of matches and I can't figure out what to do with it in the context of the structure in the moustaches example.

I have a regular expression which finds all the elements I need to highlight: I've tested it and it works.

Should I be loading up the array outside of the token function and then matching each one?  Or is there a way to work with the array?

The other issue is that I want to apply different styling depending on the (biz|cms) option in the regex - one for 'biz' and another for 'cms'.  There will be others but I'm trying to keep it simple.

This is as far as I have got.  The comments show my confusion.

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("tbs", function(config, parserConfig) {
    var tbsOverlay = {
        token: function(stream, state) {
            tbsArray = match("^<(biz|cms).([a-zA-Z0-9.]*)(\s)?(\/)?>");

            if (tbsArray != null) {
                for (i = 0; i < tbsArray.length; i++) { 
                    var result = tbsArray[i];
                    //Do I need to stream.match each element now to get hold of each bit of text?
                    //Or is there some way to identify and tag all the matches?

                }
            }

            //Obviously this bit won't work either now - even with regex
            while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match("<biz.", false)) {}

            return null;
        }
    };

    return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.backdrop || "text/html"), tbsOverlay);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns the array as produced by `RegExp.exec` or `String.prototype.match` (see for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), so you probably don't want to iterate through it, but rather pick out specific elements the correspond to groups in your regexp (`if (result[1] == "biz") ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Look at implementation of Code Mirror method **match()** and you'll see, that it processes method parameter for two types: **string** and **RegExp**.

Your constant in

```
stream.match("<biz.")
```

is of string type.

Define it in **RegExp** type:

```js
tbsArray = /<biz./g
```

Thus, your stream will be matched with RegExp.

Comment: That's all great, but the problem is how to use the matched result in the example.  In my example, I start with a match - any idea how to process it? tbsArray = match("^<(biz|cms).([a-zA-Z0-9.]*)(\s)?(\/)?>");